# How to escape double quotes in a title attribute

Tags: html, escaping, quotes

I am trying to use a string that contains double quotes in the title attribute of an anchor. So far I tried these:

```
<a href=".." title="Some \"text\"">Some text</a>
<!-- The title looks like `Some \` --!>
```

and

```
<a href=".." title="Some &quot;text&quot;">Some text</a>
<!-- The title looks like `Some ` --!>
```

Please note that using single quotes is *not* an option.

Comment: @Haim read the question… it says "single quotes is not an option".

Comment: On firefox second example looks fine.

Comment: @harpax - I was just curious why single quotes are not an option?

Comment: @nils - you right , I did not notice

Comment: Single quotes are not valid html.

Comment: Your second example should work absolutely perfectly. In which browser are you seeing the problem?

Comment: @harpax: maybe you should clarify the "single quotes are not an option"-requirement. I would have guessed that you ment single quotes "inside 'the' string" are not an option (as being displayed to the user), but just flipping single and double quotes as Haim showed above would be OK.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593800/how-to-have-quotation-marks-in-html-input-values , since escapes are the same for every attribute

Comment: I use this small easy method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6234804/104380

Comment: The canonical is *[What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945)*. It covers both attributes, text, and HTML.

Answer (score 361, accepted):

This variant -

```html
<a title="Some &quot;text&quot;">Hover me</a>
```

Is correct and it works as expected - you see normal quotes in rendered page.

Comment: Yep. `<a href="#" title="Foo &quot;Bar&quot;">Testing</a>` and `<a href="#" title="Smart quotes &#8221;Bar&#8220;">Testing too</a>` work for me.

Comment: @Maris : Well... i don't see normal quotes in rendered page when I make &quot; (Firefox, Chrome). Why?

Comment: @Maris, same problem here. See the text "&quot;" appear in both IE and Chrome when the user mouses over the element.

Comment: Amazingly worked with html content embedded within attribute (for javascript to produce editable textarea): `data-editable-note="<?php echo str_replace('"', '&quot;', $note); ?>"><?php echo mark::up($note); ?></div>`

Answer (score 38):

Here's a snippet of the HTML escape characters taken from [a cached page on archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20130727202338/http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B280015193F87256C47007456E7):

```
&#060   |   <   less than sign
&#064   |   @   at sign
&#093   |   ]   right bracket
&#123   |   {   left curly brace
&#125   |   }   right curly brace
&#133   |   …   ellipsis
&#135   |   ‡   double dagger
&#146   |   ’   right single quote
&#148   |   ”   right double quote
&#150   |   –   short dash
&#153   |   ™   trademark
&#162   |   ¢   cent sign
&#165   |   ¥   yen sign
&#169   |   ©   copyright sign
&#172   |   ¬   logical not sign
&#176   |   °   degree sign
&#178   |   ²   superscript 2
&#185   |   ¹   superscript 1
&#188   |   ¼   fraction 1/4
&#190   |   ¾   fraction 3/4
&#247   |   ÷   division sign
&#8221  |   ”   right double quote
&#062   |   >   greater than sign
&#091   |   [   left bracket
&#096   |   `   back apostrophe
&#124   |   |   vertical bar
&#126   |   ~   tilde
&#134   |   †   dagger
&#145   |   ‘   left single quote
&#147   |   “   left double quote
&#149   |   •   bullet
&#151   |   —   longer dash
&#161   |   ¡   inverted exclamation point
&#163   |   £   pound sign
&#166   |   ¦   broken vertical bar
&#171   |   «   double left than sign
&#174   |   ®   registered trademark sign
&#177   |   ±   plus or minus sign
&#179   |   ³   superscript 3
&#187   |   »   double greater-than sign
&#189   |   ½   fraction 1/2
&#191   |   ¿   inverted question mark
&#8220  |   “   left double quote
&#8212  |   —   dash
```

Answer (score 10):

The escape code `&#34;` can also be used instead of `&quot;`.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you can use JavaScript to solve your cross-browser problem. It uses a different escape mechanism, one with which you're obviously already familiar:

```js
(reference-to-the-tag).title = "Some \"text\"";
```

It doesn't strictly separate the functions of HTML, JavaScript, and CSS the way folks want you to nowadays, but whom do you need to make happy? Your users or techies you don't know?

Comment: Overkill when the desired esult can be achived in a far more straightforward manner.

Answer (score 4):

Using `&quot;` is the way to do it. I tried your second code snippet, and it works in both Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 3):

It may work with any character from the [HTML Escape character list](http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B280015193F87256C47007456E7), but I had the same problem with a Java project. I used `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHTML("Testing \" <br> <p>")` and the title was `<a href=".." title="Test&quot; &lt;br&gt; &lt;p&gt;">Testing</a>`.

It only worked for me when I changed the StringEscapeUtils to `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavascript("Testing \" <br> <p>")` and it worked in every browser.

Comment: best solution in my opinion

Comment: Fine if you're using Java, but as the original inquirer is asking for HTML, perhaps this is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one situation where using single quotes will not work and that is if you are creating the markup "on the fly" from JavaScript. You use single quotes to contain the string and then any property in the markup can have double quotes for its value.