# How can we display 2 1/4'' in asp.net boundfeild?

Tags: asp.net

How can we display header text value 2 1/4'' in asp.net boundfield ? below is my code.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="2 1/4"" HeaderText="2 1/4"" --82" ReadOnly="true" DataFormatString="{0:C2}" HtmlEncode="False" Visible="false">
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <ItemStyle Width="40px" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        </asp:BoundField>
```

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes are perfectly valid delimiters, you can use them when you need to put a double quote in your content.

```
HeaderText='2 1/4"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also encode the double quote as

```
&quot;
```

Also see [How to escape double quotes in title attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752769/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-title-attribute) there are lots of other recommendations and follow up reading.