# Wordpress cuts image title at &quot;?

Tags: wordpress

The titles for my images are cut as soon as I have a `&quot;` in them. So when I have this in my source:

```
<img src="..." title="This is &quot;my&quot; title" />
```

I get `This is` as title when I move the mouse over the image. So as you see, it cuts the title at the first `&quot;`. The problem is, that the source of the image is mixed up when I look at it using Firebug. So it seems that Wordpress can not handle quotes in quotes.

Any ideas where to look or how to solve this? I am running the latest Wordpress.

Thanks

**Solution:** If that happens, using `&amp;quot;` did the trick. I applied a filter on `the_content` as vard suggested to apply it on all images.

Comment: Where can we check the issue? This is localized and we need to check the page.

Comment: When you say "mouse over the image", the tooltip is the default one of the browser, or a custom one?

Comment: @vard: Yes, the standard browser tooltip. The problem is, that the source of the image is mixed up when I look at it using Firebug. So it seems that Wordpress can not handle quotes in quotes?

Comment: I don't think this have anything to do with Wordpress - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3752794/3305116 (look on Krzysztof comment)

Comment: what is the html doctype of the page (along with other settings), are the quotes themselves escaped (i.e not `&quot;` but `&amp;quot;`)? all these are relevant. You can also try single quotes (`&#39;`)

Comment: @vard: If I test that in a plain html page, it works. I does not work in Wordpress context though. So it must have something to do with Wordpress, I think.

Comment: Well the HTML you quoted is your HTML browser output right?

Comment: Nope, its the source code I am using, when I look at the generated source using Firebug, its messed up. The source is always ok, just the generated source is messed up and so the title is cut.

Comment: Need more details then - how do you display your image? "its in the source code", you mean you pasted that in the wp editor in source mode?

Comment: `&amp;quot;` works, just tested ... but I can not change 100+ posts escaping the & as well. There must be some other solution?

Comment: Put a filter on [`the_content`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) like in Jenis answer, but with `str_replace('&quot;', '&amp;quot;', $content);`

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to your `functions.php`.

```
 function convert_quotes( $title) {

        $title = str_replace('"', '&quot;', $title);

        return $title;
    }
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'convert_quotes', 10, 2 );
```

Not tested but hope will work for you.

Comment: I don't think the image title attribute is displayed through `the_title`

Comment: This would not help, it will convert " to the html entity, but I am using the entity already.