# Javascript not passing entire variable string

Tags: javascript, php

I found this neat code online that does exactly what I need. The problem I'm having is that the variable is not passing the entire value.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#add_id").click(function() {
            var value = $("#entered_id").val();
            $("#list_id").append("<option value =" + value + " selected>" + value + "</option>");
        });
    });    
</script>




<select id='entered_id'>
    <option value='This is a test message'>test</option>";
</select>


<button id="add_id">Add</button>


<h2>Entered IDs</h2>
<form name="test" method="POST" action="test2.php">
    <select id="list_id" name="list_id" multiple="multiple"> </select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

On `test2.php` the variable `$list_id` comes in as "This" instead of "This is a test".

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put the string values arround quotes `'` :

```
$("#list_id").append("<option value =" + value + " selected>" + value + "</option>");
```

Should be :

```
$("#list_id").append("<option value ='" + value + "' selected>" + value + "</option>");
_____________________________________^_____________^
```

In other words, the generated option html looked like `<option value=This is a test>`, making `is`, `a`, and `test` invalid/unknown attributes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In other words, the generated option html looked like `<option value=This is a test>`, making `is`, `a`, and `test` invalid/unknown attributes.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB for your intervention, can i update my answer using your explanation?

Comment: of course... you got the right answer, this just expands on WHY it's the right anwer.

Comment: If the value happens to include a double-quote, he'll have the same problem again. He should add some code to [replace `"` with `&quot;` inside the string.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752769/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-title-attribute)