# bind html using c# and javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I want to bind html from c#. I tried with the below code it's working

```
HtmlTextWriter.write("<a onclick=\"window.open('', '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes').document.write('<p>test<P>')\">);
```

then I try to add img tag in it then html is breaking

eg:

```
 HtmlTextWriter.write("<a onclick=\"window.open('', '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes').document.write('<img src=\"path\">')\">);
```

please help to solve this.

Comment: Define *"breaking"* please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&quot;` instead of actual quote character ".
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3752794/7988857).

```
string html = "<a onclick=\"window.open('', '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes').document.write('<img src=&quot;path&quot;>')\">";
HtmlTextWriter.Write(html);
```

See this html in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b1kk9oa7/1/).

Comment: I passing base64 image in <img src"">,but it's not showing full image in new opening window.Base64 content showing correctly in img src,while click on link to open new window it shows half of image.please help to resolve

Comment: @user8278302 : Can you post the base64 image string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @" your string here " in C#. But for every " you have to use ""

```
HtmlTextWriter.write(@"<a onclick=""window.open('', '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes').document.write('<img src=""path"">')"">");
```