# (Hybris) Problem importing html classes in impex

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex, hybris-data-hub

I'm trying to import an impex with html and it appears in the webpage without the class. For example this h1 class (content-page__title) doesn't appear.

```
UPDATE CMSParagraphComponent; $contentCV[unique = true]; uid[unique = true]; content[lang = $lang]

; ; CMSParagraph-FrequentQuestionsPage       ; "<h1 class='content-page__title'>Preguntas frecuentes</h1>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect pair of quotes....

Use like below,

```
UPDATE CMSParagraphComponent; $contentCV[unique = true]; uid[unique = true]; content[lang = $lang]

; ; CMSParagraph-FrequentQuestionsPage       ; "<h1 class=""content-page__title"">Preguntas frecuentes</h1>"
```

Also you can use html encoding like **&quot ;**

refer below link,

[Escape_Double_Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752769/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-a-title-attribute)