# Single quote escape in JavaScript function parameters

Tags: javascript, quote

I need to escape single quotes in JavaScript function parameters to avoid this:

```
onclick="Javascript:INSERT_PRODUCT('188267','WILL AND GRACE','32311','L'ANNIVERSARIO DINOZZE ','20101113|04|18|','13/11/2010 0.00.00','CANALE 5  ',this);"
```

But I need to escape them inside a function call since I do not know the values that will be passed (db variables I can't escape from the database).

Is there a function that allows me to do something like the following?

```
onclick="Javascript:function(escape(param1), escape(param2), escape(param3));"
```

Comment: `'` = `\'` (Just as you would a normal string). And because you're inserting it in the markup, either _you_ would need to escape it, or if a server-side language is generating it make sure _it_ escapes it.

Comment: Yyou can put your parameters inside `escape(param)`

Comment: The label `Javascript:` is not needed there. You should use other ways to bind event handlers: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html, then you don't have to worry about quotes.

Comment: @EmmanuelN: `escape` url escapes it, not translates quotes.

Comment: @DanieleDiPunzio: For a definitive answer, can you show how you're generating the markup? Is this PHP, ASP, etc. generated, or are you hard-coding the onclick binding yourself? (If you're hard-coding it, you'll just need to be conscience of replacing the quotes--nothing is going to do it for you.)

Comment: I tried using escape(param) but the result is myfunction('', '', '') ando so on...

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using an internal software developed by my company. this product generates vb.net and html code with hardcoded stuff. I can only define an onclick function for my button, that's why I should escape single quotes in function call.

Comment: Look into HTML Attribute escaping:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015345/how-to-properly-escape-quotes-inside-html-attributes

Answer (score 20):

```
 JSON.stringify(plainTextStr).replace(/&/, "&amp;").replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
```

will produce a string you can safely embed in a quoted attribute and which will have the same meaning when seen by the JavaScript interpreter.

The only caveat is that some [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) newlines (U+2028 and U+2029) [need to be escaped](http://es5.github.com/#x7.3) before being embedded in JavaScript string literals, but JSON only requires that `\r` and `\n` be escaped.

Answer (score 11):

Escape the apostrophe with a backslash:

```
onclick="INSERT_PRODUCT('188267','WILL AND GRACE ','32311','L\'ANNIVERSARIO DI NOZZE ','20101113|04|18|','13/11/2010 0.00.00','CANALE 5 ',this);"
```

Comment: Please remove the `Javascript:`. It's not wrong to put it there, but it is of no use either and less experienced developers might think it is needed.

Comment: I need a function to perform the escape inside the myfunction call since that's the only place I can access. Any suggestion?

Comment: This will fail if the string contains `"`, `&#27;`, '&#x5c;' or any other entity that encodes single or double quotes or backslash.  For example, the string `'foo " onmouseover=alert(1)` contains no single quote, yet when embedded in an HTML attribute, exploits an XSS vulnerability.  Similarly, `'foo &#x5c;` will fail, because the JavaScript parser will see `\`, not `&#x5c;` so the close quote will be interpreted as part of the string so if the next string value is ` alert(1)) // `, then that will be treated as literal JavaScript, resulting in arbitrary script execution too.

Answer (score 7):

It's maybe not totally clear from the question, but assuming that all you want is to send this to a PHP script for storing in a database, you of course would ideally utilize PHP's various methods such as `stripslashes()` -- but if you're really not trying to get too fancy, simply adding 1 slash in front of any single quote is enough to send a SQL query right into PHP from the client-side. It's *not safe*, but maybe not necessary either.

```
str.replace(/'/g, "\\'"); // escaping \ with \, so used 2x
```

does the trick., like for example in something like this:

```
var body = $('#body').val().replace(/'/g, "\\'");
myCustomSQLqueryFunction("UPDATE mytable SET `content`='"+ body +"';" );
```

MySQL will now store your `body` like you see it in the form field.

Comment: I was testing this and noticed that MySQL simply removes fancy single quotes like ` so you'd have to escape those as well.

Answer (score 3):

This function worked for me (it removes and restores the quote again):
Guessing that the data to be sent is the value of an input element,

```
var Url = encodeURIComponent($('#userInput').val().replace("'","\\'"));
```

Then get the original text again:

```
var originalText = decodeURIComponent(Url);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var cmpdetail = cmpdetail.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
```

its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use single quote for defining JavaScript strings.  Then I escape my embedded double quotes as follows.

This is how I do it, basically `str.replace(/[\""]/g, '\\"')`.

```js
var display = document.getElementById('output');
var str = 'class="whatever-foo__input" id="node-key"';
display.innerHTML = str.replace(/[\""]/g, '\\"');

//will return class=\"whatever-foo__input\" id=\"node-key\"
```

```html
<span id="output"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue recently, and solved it by replacing the single quote with the corresponding unicode (`&#39;`)

Initially my code was this, resulting in me getting results that were cut off (e.g. `Jane's Coffee` became just `Jane` in the output).

```
b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
```

When I introduced unicode replacement (shown below), I got the exact output I wanted

```
b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i].replace("'", "&#39;") + "'>";
```