# How do I escape a single quote ( ' ) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

**UPDATE:**
I want to give an updated answer to this question. First, let me state if you're attempting to accomplish what I have below, I recommend that you manage events by [adding event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk:DOM/element.addEventListener) instead. I highly recommend that you utilize [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) for your project and use their syntax to [manage event listeners](http://api.jquery.com/on/) over using DOM.

**QUESTION**

Okay, I am basically doing this:

```
document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = "<img src='something' onmouseover='change(\'ex1\')' />";
```

I don't want double quotes (") where I put the \'. I only want a single quote, so I am trying to not make it put a double when it is used. I am trying to reach this in the final outcome.

```
<img src="something" onmouseover="change('ex1')" />
```

Escaping isn't working for me.

My marked answer works fine, however, the cleaner (and more professional-looking way, IMO) is  [loganfsmyth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16134953/1754890).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744315/single-quote-escape-in-javascript-function-parameters

Answer (score 202, accepted):

You should always consider what the browser will see by the end. In this case, it will see this:

```
<img src='something' onmouseover='change(' ex1')' />
```

In other words, the "onmouseover" attribute is just `change(`, and there's another "attribute" called `ex1')'` with no value.

The truth is, HTML does not use `\` for an escape character. But it does recognise `&quot;` and `&apos;` as escaped quote and apostrophe, respectively.

Armed with this knowledge, use this:

```
document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = "<img src='something' onmouseover='change(&quot;ex1&quot;)' />";
```

... That being said, you could just use JavaScript quotes:

```
document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = "<img src='something' onmouseover='change(\"ex1\")' />";
```

Comment: …or, even better, don't use inline attribue handlers at all; especially on elements created via javascript.

Comment: I am not able to understand the question what does ex1 mean ?

Comment: @SurajJain `'ex1'` is just an arbitrary string value that OP wanted to pass into a function.

Answer (score 184):

The answer here is very simple:

You're already containing it in double quotes, so there's no need to escape it with `\`.

If you want to escape single quotes in a single quote string:

```
var string = 'this isn\'t a double quoted string';
var string = "this isn\"t a single quoted string";
//           ^         ^ same types, hence we need to escape it with a backslash
```

or if you want to escape `\'`, you can escape the bashslash to `\\` and the quote to `\'` like so:

```
var string = 'this isn\\\'t a double quoted string';
//                    vvvv
//                     \ ' (the escaped characters)
```

However, if you contain the string with a different quote type, you don't need to escape:

```
var string = 'this isn"t a double quoted string';
var string = "this isn't a single quoted string";
//           ^        ^ different types, hence we don't need escaping
```

Comment: Sir `<input type = "text" value = "abc"   id="text"/>`
  
 `<input type = "button" value ="pressme" onclick= "alert('getElementById("text").value')" >`
 This is not working can you point out an error ?

Comment: @SurajJain First of all you shouldn't use the quotes inside of alert - you're outputting a text value, and secondly you should either escape your quotes or change their type in your script.

Comment: Thanks , can you also tell me what line height is ?

Comment: @SurajJain The comments here aren't really good for any kind of irrelevant discussion, but a line height is the height of the lines. You can [check out the `line-height` entry on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)

Comment: I don't think this answer really addresses the issue in question. Loganfsmith answer was the epiphany for me:
`"<img src='abc' onmouseover='change(&apos;any string here&apos;)' />";`
Also the example text in your strings is confusing.

Answer (score 41):

You can escape a `'` in JavaScript like `\'`

Answer (score 23):

Since the values are actually inside of an HTML attribute, you should use `&apos;`

```
"<img src='something' onmouseover='change(&apos;ex1&apos;)' />";
```

Comment: This worked for me when trying to use inside of a text/x-template.

Answer (score 5):

```
    document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = "<img src=\"something\" onmouseover=\"change('ex1')\" />";
```

OR

```
    document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = '<img src="something" onmouseover="change(\'ex1\')" />';
```

It should be working...