# Passing encoded string to Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass this string to a javascript function:

```
<a href="javascript:InsertPhrase('Let%27s%20groove')">Let's groove</a>
```

and this is the function:

```
function InsertPhrase(ThisPhrase) {
 document.getElementById("F1").value = document.getElementById("F1").value + decodeURIComponent(ThisPhrase) + " ";
}
```

I know the apostrophe is screwing things up but I thought that encoding it would fix it, however the function does not get called. Please can someone tell me why and how to fix it?

Comment: Why would it get called, you put a JS function into the `href` tag... when do you want this to be called?

Comment: Ew. Linking to JavaScript is a very bad thing to do. Try `href="#" onclick='InsertPhrase('Let\'s groove')"`, or adding an event listener.

Comment: It worked for everything which didn't include apostrophes, I didn't realise I was doing it the wrong way in general! I'll use onclick instead...

Comment: @AndyGroom the reason it wasn't working for the apostrophe is because it's being evaluated as a _URL_ first which is decoding the url-encoded symbols before the _JavaScript_ interpreter sees it, so you're passing `InsertPhrase('Let's groove')` to the interpreter, in which your string is terminated early

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onclick` to call a function instead of `href`.

`<a href="#" onclick="InsertPhrase('Let%27s%20groove')">Let's groove</a>`

And for other issue look at here [how to escape a single quote in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134910/how-to-escape-a-single-quote-in-javascript)

Comment: Yes I didn't realise the way I used was bad practice, it works perfectly with onclick.