# How to convert html to variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem while convert html to javascript variable.

**My HTML Code**

```
<div onclick="openfullanswer('2','Discription part','This is the code part');">
```

I want to create this html code dynamically, but I have the problem in quote(" and ')

**I tried like below**

```
for(i=0;i<result.length;i++)
{       
        strVar +="<div onclick='openfullanswer("+result[i].ReplyID+",'"+result[i].Description+"','"+result[i].Code+"');'>Test code</div>";
}
```

[**https://jsfiddle.net/8782n60z/1/**](https://jsfiddle.net/8782n60z/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Way 1:** 
You should have to change the sequence of single and double quotes and have to escape the single quotes with '\' in on-click function arguments

Please check the below snippet for more understanding.

```js
var result=[];
var obj=new Object();
obj.ReplyID=1;
obj.Description="This is my description";
obj.Code="This is my Code Part";

result.push(obj);



strVar="";
for(i=0;i<result.length;i++)
{       
  strVar +='<div onclick="openfullanswer(\''+result[i].ReplyID+'\',\''+result[i].Description+'\',\''+result[i].Code+'\');">Test code</div>';
}

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=strVar;


function openfullanswer(replyid,desc,code)
{
  alert("success");

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">

</div>
```

**Way 2:**
Don't change the sequence of quotes.
Only change the onclick event declaration quotes from signle to double and escape double quotes with '\' and you need not have to change anything.

Please check the below snippet for more understanding.

```js
var result=[];
var obj=new Object();
obj.ReplyID=1;
obj.Description="This is my description";
obj.Code="This is my Code Part";

result.push(obj);


strVar="";
for(i=0;i<result.length;i++)
{       
    strVar +="<div onclick=\"openfullanswer("+result[i].ReplyID+",'"+result[i].Description+"','"+result[i].Code+"');\">Test code</div>";
}

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=strVar;


function openfullanswer(replyid,desc,code)
{
alert("success");

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
strVar +="<div onclick=\"openfullanswer('"+result[i].ReplyID+"','"+result[i].Description+"','"+result[i].Code+"');\">Test code</div>";
```

try this.

Comment: can you explain more please your answer?

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote produces the following:

```
<div onclick='openfullanswer(1,'This is my description','This is my Code Part');'>Test code</div>
```

The above is not valid since there are single quotes inside the value of `onclick`.

You will need to escape these characters.

```
strVar +="<div onclick=\"window.openfullanswer("+result[i].ReplyID+",'"+result[i].Description+"','"+result[i].Code+"');\">Test code</div>";
```

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134910/how-to-escape-a-single-quote-in-javascript) an article in SO explaining this matter in detail.

See a working demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/8782n60z/3/

P.S. I changed a bit the way to declare and call the function because it gave an error.

Comment: K Can you please give me more explanation about escape character

Answer (score 1):

You can use `template literal`

```js
var result = [];
var obj = new Object();
obj.ReplyID = 1;
obj.Description = "This is my description";
obj.Code = "This is my Code Part";

result.push(obj);

strVar = "";
for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  strVar += `<div 
               onclick="openfullanswer('${result[i].ReplyID}'
                                       , '${result[i].Description}'
                                       , '${result[i].Code}');">
               Test code
             </div>`;
}

function openfullanswer(replyid, desc, code) {
  alert("success");
  console.log(replyid, desc, code);
}

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = strVar;
```

```html
<div id="test">

</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8782n60z/5/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building the string you could also use **document.createElement** to generate your **div**. And then append it to the parent #test

```js
var result=[];
var obj=new Object();
obj.ReplyID=1;
obj.Description="This is my description";
obj.Code="This is my Code Part";

result.push(obj);

var div;
for(i=0;i<result.length;i++)
{       
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = 'Test code'
  div.onclick = openfullanswer;
}
document.getElementById("test").appendChild(div);

function openfullanswer(replyid,desc,code)
{
  alert("success");
}
```

```html
<div id="test">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I can not able to solve my problem by the method because, I am generating not only this div.

Comment: You shouldn't have to build complex DOM elements with strings. If that array is going to have several objects and you want a div with a onclick callback for each object... Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/o9ctpuno ... I did it my way. Hope it helps, and I'd be glad to explain it further if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Since what you need has already been answered above, I'll just add that the way you are trying to access and manipulate DOM element is not safe or recommended way of handling dom elements. Instead of directly writing to DOM, its better to make use of [addEventListner()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) function and bind your element to it.

For instance, instead of writing ,

```
strVar +="<div onclick='openfullanswer("+result[i].ReplyID+",'"+result[i].Description+"','"+result[i].Code+"');'>Test code</div>";
```

you should be instead doing

```
strVar.outerHTML += '<input id="btncall" ...>'

document.getElementById ("btncall").addEventListener ("click", openfullanswer(parameters), false);
```