# Jquery populate list freak error

Tags: javascript, jquery, database

I'm facing a freak problem in jquery. When I try to populate a list from a table it becomes empty if it contains a special character like sid'ahmed. When I change it to sidi ahmed it works perfectly. This is my code to populate two lists:

```
$.getJSON("get-data.php?dat=driver", function(data) {
  var stringToAppend1 = "<option value='" + day_Shift + "'>" + day_Shift + "</option>";
  var stringToAppend2 = "<option value='" + night_Shift + "'>" + night_Shift + "</option>";

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    stringToAppend1 += "<option value='" + val.prenom + " / " + val.nom + " : " + val.telephone + "'>" + val.prenom + " / " + val.nom + " : " + val.telephone + "</option>";
    stringToAppend2 += "<option value='" + val.prenom + " / " + val.nom + " : " + val.telephone + "'>" + val.prenom + " / " + val.nom + " : " + val.telephone + "</option>";
  });

  $("#night_Shift_text" + id).html(stringToAppend2);
  $("#day_Shift_text" + id).html(stringToAppend1);
});
```

Comment: have you tried escaping the input? It's a bad idea to just insert stuff from external sources that way (XSS voulnerabilty). It also creates your problem.

Comment: the single quote is the string delimiter. you need to escape it when it occurs inside a string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428572/how-to-escape-single-quote, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134910/how-to-escape-a-single-quote-in-javascript

Comment: it is already in database I want just to use it to populate my list

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the single quote by using replace function as shown below. Use this replace whereever needed.

```
day_Shift = day_Shift.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: how to implement this in my exemple