# Using Javascript to write HTML inputs which call Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'll give you an example of what I'm trying to do.

In Javascript:

```
document.innerHTML += "<input type='button' id='moveButton' value='a' onclick='webInput('a');'>"
```

The problem is that the html being written has two levels of quotes, and I can't figure out how to format the second level of quotes here:

```
webInput('a')
```

In my Javascript file, I have one function write the inputs into the HTML at the end of the function, then clicking the inputs calls the next function, until eventually the inputs are rewritten.

I know the answer probably has something to do with Escape Characters, but I was confused as to how to format them because the text is being passed back and forther between Javascript and HTML, which use different Escape Characters.

Comment: Just don't use inline JavaScript at all :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your button within the javascript code and define the method therein.

```
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.addEventListener('click',function(){
   doSomething();
});
//This method adds your button to body
document.body.appendChild(button)
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful advice.

Comment: I am glad to hear that :) If you want, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking 'tick' button

Answer (score -1):

If you have requirements to add this as string to the document, you need to escape quotes:

```
"<input type='button' id='moveButton' value='a' onclick='webInput(\"a\")'>"
```

great answer with rules for escaping here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16134942/5727598

Also, you should use [innerHtml](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property for element in which you want to pass your string but be sure it will remove all content there;

If no requirements, create button and upend to the body:

```
var input = document.createElement('input');

input.type = 'button';
input.id = 'moveButton';
input.value = 'a';

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
   webInput(this.value); //if you need to pass input value as parameter
})

document.body.appendChild(input);
```