# Are there alternatives to using quotes in js?

Tags: javascript, html

For example in the following javascript code if you use single quotes to open `document.getElementById('code').value =` You'll reach a problem at `window.open` where you cannot use single quotes, to open it. That would close the `getElementById` and break the code. You also cannot use double quotes, because if double quotes are used you'll run into the same issue when putting quotes around `newwindow`. Are there ways around this?

```
   function genorateCode() {
  var account = document.getElementById("account").value;
  var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
  document.getElementById('code').value = '<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><a href="' + url + '" ' + ' onclick="window.open("' + url + '", "newwindow", "width=400,height=500"); return false;">' + '<div class="button"><img src="https://s15.postimg.org/mfpd2ki8r/icon.png" width="16">@' + account + '</div></a>';
}
```

(this is all put into a text area, so users can use the 'generated' code)

```
<textarea readonly id="code"></textarea>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape a single quote ( ' ) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134910/how-to-escape-a-single-quote-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ` with variable interpolation ${} like in the following fiddle :

```js
function generateCode() {
  var account = document.getElementById("account").value;
  var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
  document.getElementById('code').value = `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><a href="${url}" onclick="window.open('${url}', 'newwindow', 'width=400,height=500'); return false;"><div class="button"><img src="https://s15.postimg.org/mfpd2ki8r/icon.png" width="16">${account}</div></a>`;
}

window.generateCode = generateCode;
```

```html
<p>
Account: <input id="account" />
</p>
<p>
URL: <input id="url" /> 
</p>
<p>
Code: <textarea readonly id="code"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
<button onclick="javascript:generateCode()">
Get the code!
</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ` to surround your string, which is the button beside 1 on your keyboard, usually called backtick.

This gives you access to some other syntax, so you could do something like this

```
function genorateCode() {
  var account = document.getElementById("account").value;
  var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
  document.getElementById('code').value = `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><a href="${url}" onclick="window.open("${url}", "newwindow", "width=400,height=500"); return false;"> <div class="button"><img src="https://s15.postimg.org/mfpd2ki8r/icon.png" width="16">@${account}</div></a>`;
}
```