# Javascript SyntaxError: missing

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm trying to put 2 scripts in 1 js file and i'm getting:

```
SyntaxError: missing } after property list
note: { opened at line 9, column 19
```

But as far as I check all the curly brackets are closed, not sure what the real issue is.

## Code

```
// country
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $('select[name="country"]').on('change', function() {
      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
      });
       var CountryId = $(this).val();
        if(CountryId) {
            $.ajax({
              url: '{{ url('getprovinces') }}/'+encodeURI(CountryId),
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "json",
              success:function(data) {
                $('select[name="province"]').empty();
                var options = data.map(function(state) {
                    return $("<option class='form-control'>").val(state.id)
                                        .text(state.name);
                });
                $('select[name="province"]').empty().append(options);
              }
            });
        }else{
          $('select[name="province"]').empty().append("<option class='form-control' value='' selected>Select</option>");
        }
    });
});
```

error comes from this line:

```
url: '{{ url('getprovinces') }}/'+encodeURI(CountryId),
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using laravel framework?

Comment: I think, your code is not in laravel blade, it is in a separate js file. Don't use blade syntax in javascript

Comment: @Shidersz yes..

Comment: @TamilSelvanC yes it is in separate file

Comment: `"{{ url('getprovinces') }}/"+encodeURI(CountryId)` This will work

Comment: can you please provide more info as all requested.

Comment: @RajenderJoshi no it doesn't

Comment: @RajenderJoshi if you do so, do you think `url('getprovinces')` will be populated?

Comment: @SanjaysinhZala i select country and it returns provinces names the only obstacle is that my js code isn't in my blade file it's loading from external js file

Comment: @PyaePhyoeShein i have the exact code in different app and it's working the only difference is in that app my js file is in blade file and in this one is in external js file

Comment: Then you need to do this within <script> tags in your layout view.

`<script>
    var getprovinces_url = "<?php echo url('getprovinces'); ?>";
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

[You need to escape the quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134910/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-javascript) or use a double-quoted string. Otherwise JS thinks the string ends on the quote after `url('` then gets confused when a variable name pops up.

Answer (score 0):

Try like that:

```
// country
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $('select[name="country"]').on('change', function() {
      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
      });
       var CountryId = $(this).val();
        if(CountryId) {
            $.ajax({
              url: '{{' + url('getprovinces') + '}}/' + encodeURI(CountryId),
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "json",
              success:function(data) {
                $('select[name="province"]').empty();
                var options = data.map(function(state) {
                    return $("<option class='form-control'>").val(state.id)
                                        .text(state.name);
                });
                $('select[name="province"]').empty().append(options);
              }
            });
        }else{
          $('select[name="province"]').empty().append("<option class='form-control' value='' selected>Select</option>");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what is value of `url('getprovinces')`?

Comment: this is the route `Route::get('/getprovinces/{countryid}','Front\AddressLists@getprovinces');` it returns provinces as json

Comment: so far, above my code is not problem. there should be problem `url('getprovinces')`

Comment: wth..!! why did you pass those kinda json data to url? better `post` method instead for those `getprovinces` data.

Comment: so you suggest i change my route to post?

Comment: yap, exactly. it should be post.

Comment: but i want to get data from database and not save to database. to getting data from database my route should be GET i think no?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
url: url('getprovinces') + '/' + encodeURI(CountryId),
```