# how to use simple alert message using TempData with Escape single asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following string in french languages which contains single quotes between the characters and words. This message I want to show in alert.

```
string Mlocal = "Ce porduit n'a pas encore été livré.";


TempData["msg_Vide"] = "<script>alert('" + Mlocal + "');</script>";
```

the alert not showing

**i use escape "`\'`" and "`&sbquo;`" and "`&#8218;`" and "`&#39;`" but not working**

passing string value is ok, but passing alert message with the special characters no ok

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape a single quote ( ' ) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134910/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the string to you view and let your view do the rest (and of course escape your single quote:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    TempData["msg_Vide"] = "Ce porduit n\\'a pas encore été livré.";
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@if(TempData["msg_Vide"] != null) { 
    <script>
        alert('@Html.Raw(TempData["msg_Vide"])')
    </script>
}
```

[image]

Comment: i use in controller

 `if (Mlocal != null)  {

                TempData["msg_Vide"] = "<script>alert('" + Mlocal + "');</script>";
                ViewBag.msg_Vide = Mlocal;
            }
else { TempData["msg_Vide"] = ""; } `

and in view : 
`@Html.Raw(TempData["msg_Vide"])`

**thank you is working now**