# need to ignore if there is any single quote char in value come from expression language without breaking javascript code

Tags: javascript

I am getting a value from the server and directly assigning it to a field using javascript. Below is the code.

```
document.getElementById('myid')='<%= myServerValue%>';
```

But the issue is when myServerValue contains single quote javascript functionality collapsed.
Since it is like `document.getElementById('myid')='myvalue'isx';` [there is a single quote]

Please tell me a solution. Using double quotes too will not be a good option, since myServerValue could contain double quotes also...

Comment: See [single quote escape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744315/single-quote-escape-in-javascript-function-parameters).

Comment: I need some client side solution using javascript, not a server side solution.

Comment: The first solution in that post is a client-side solution.

Comment: <%= myServerValue%> looked like server code to me? Is it not server side code?

Answer (score 0):

try HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode your characters at the server and somehow decode it in the javascript code.
There are a few possibilities to achieve that, you can use UTF8 like in this [demo](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-utf8.html)
The escape and unescape javascript methods are obsolete but you can try [String.fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode).

Answer (score 0):

This no the most clean solution, but it will work just as it is.

```
document.getElementById('myid')="<%= myServerValue%>";
```