# inverted commas in javascript String

Tags: javascript, php, string

Little confusion in filtering " inverted commas for a javascript string in php.

```
$data = "I'am a string my name is "String".";
// problem is in following line.
$data = str_replace("\"","\\". "\"",$data);

$data = str_replace('<br />','\n',$data);
$data = str_replace("'","\\"."'",$data);

$row['story'] = $row['story'] . "<a href=\"#scroll\" onclick=\"addtext('$data'); return false\">Send</a>";
```

**Update**
$data is some random string in a php page. I want to filter this string in simple text for a javascript function.e.g

```
 $data = "I'am a string my name is \"String\".";
```

I want to get the results like this.

```
onclick="addtext('I\'am a string my name is "String"'); return false"
```

Comment: And what is your problem here? Except poor syntax.

Comment: The code looks wierd. What are you planning to do?  BTW I think theres a syntax issue in the first line.

Comment: You forgot to escape a string in the first line. `$data = "I'am a string my name is \"String\".";`

Comment: For a JavaScript string in PHP? What exactly do you mean? How are you getting the string? And, what ***exactly*** are you trying to do? I'm sorry, but your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: onclick="addtext('') I want to get result here but when there is a double quote then there are lots of double quotes in result

Comment: I added some more information.

Comment: [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843010/need-to-ignore-if-there-is-any-single-quote-char-in-value-come-from-expression-l/18843281#18843281)

Comment: Actually your onclick="addtext('I\'am a string my name is "String"'); return false" is not possible because this => " in "String" is the end of your addtext function

Comment: I done it by replacing it with some other character and later I replaced this other character to double quotes in upon calling java script

Answer (score 0):

Why you make:

```
$data = str_replace("\"","\\". "\"",$data);
```

and not

```
$data = str_replace("'","\'",$data);
```

because your addtext function can't be working because a \ is missing in front of this => " "String" it must be \"String\"

I hope this is what you want to do.

And as a tip it's often easier to use

```
'...blablabla....<a href="la.html">la</a>'
```

instead of

```
"....blablabla....<a href=\"la.html\">la</a>"
```

Comment: Original string was

When you both said "I do." The two of you became as one,

The results are

<a href="#scroll" onclick="addtext('When you both said \" i="" do.\"the="" two="" of="" you="" became="" as=""">Send This Message</a>