# escaping special characters in javascript to use them in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Javascript in my php application.I am stuck in one line\this is the line

```
'<td><input type="button" onClick="$(this).closest('tr').remove();" value="x" class="btn btn-primary"></td>'
```

I want to concatenate that ('tr') that is present with closest.

There is issue with double quotes and single quote.

Comment: We'll need more context. What is that string? Where? Is that in the PHP code or the JavaScript code? what does "concatenate that ('tr') that is present with closest" mean?

Comment: This seems to be JavaScript code in a PHP application..

Comment: Use jQuery's `on` instead of 1990s style `onclick` attributes and it won't be an issue.

Comment: i think there is proble with double quote and single quotes that are used in that entire line and the problem is at ('tr')

Comment: function addnewrow()
        {
        var n= ($('#inv-detail tr').length-0)+1;
         var row='<tr>'+
        '<th><b class="no">' + n + '</b></th>'+
        '<td><input type="text" name="p_name[]" class="p_name form-control"/></td>'+
        '<td><textarea rows="1" cols="3" name="p_description[]" class="p_description form-control"/></td>'+
     
        '<td><input type="button" onClick="$(this).closest('tr').remove();" value="x" class="btn btn-primary"></td>'

        '</tr>';
       
        }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744315/single-quote-escape-in-javascript-function-parameters

Comment: you can normally escape quotes with backslash `\"`  ie. `string = 'I\'m a "string"'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using single quote within a single quoted string. So you have to escape the quotes with \

```
echo '<td><input type="button" onClick="$(this).closest(\'tr\').remove();" value="x" class="btn btn-primary"></td>';
```

for javascript also it is the same

```
var x = '<td><input type="button" onClick="$(this).closest(\'tr\').remove();" value="x" class="btn btn-primary"></td>';
```