# Missing ) after argument list. (line 704, file "Code")

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, formula

I'm trying to setFormula and I keep getting an error about Missing ) in the code. I understand that it's the double quotes that are messing me up, and that \ can escape those out, but I don't know which double quotes need to be escaped. Can someone shed insight into this?

`cell.setFormula('=({filter('Master Fulfillment Sheet'!$A$5705:$A,'Master Fulfillment Sheet'!D5705:D="Published",'Master Fulfillment Sheet'!D5705:D<>"",'Master Fulfillment Sheet'!G5705:G>(today()-30));filter('Tobe Fulfillment Sheet'!$A$2:$A,'Tobe Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"",'Tobe Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"Published",'Tobe Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"Needs Attention",'Tobe Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"*Onsite Blog Post*",'Tobe Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"Order Cancelled");filter('Kendra Fulfillment Sheet'!$A$2:$A,'Kendra Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"",'Kendra Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"Published",'Kendra Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"Needs Attention",'Kendra Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"*Onsite Blog Post*",'Kendra Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"Order Cancelled");filter('Megan Fulfillment Sheet'!$A$2:$A,'Megan Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"",'Megan Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"Published",'Megan Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"Needs Attention",'Megan Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"*Onsite Blog Post*",'Megan Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"Order Cancelled");filter('Kyle Fulfillment Sheet'!$A$2:$A,'Kyle Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"",'Kyle Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"Published",'Kyle Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"Needs Attention",'Kyle Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"*Onsite Blog Post*",'Kyle Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"Order Cancelled");filter('Mary Fulfillment Sheet'!$A$2:$A,'Mary Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"",'Mary Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"Published",'Mary Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"Needs Attention",'Mary Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"*Onsite Blog Post*",'Mary Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"Order Cancelled");filter('Mariah Fulfillment Sheet'!$A$2:$A,'Mariah Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"",'Mariah Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"Published",'Mariah Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"Needs Attention",'Mariah Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"*Onsite Blog Post*",'Mariah Fulfillment Sheet'!E2:E<>"Order Cancelled")})');`

Comment: Have you tried changing the opening and closing single quote character to a grave character - so single quotes inside do not need escaping? If that doesn't help, what character in the line is the error occuring at?

Comment: Please, can you format the code in more readibility appereance?

Answer (score 0):

The problem es that code use `'` as a string delimiter and as a sheet name delimiter as it is used on Google Sheets but on a Google Apps Script should be escaped by preceding them with `\`.

Basically, replace `'Master Fulfillment Sheet'` by `\'Master Fulfillment Sheet\'`.

Related question

- [Single quote escape in JavaScript function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8744315/1595451)