# Single Quote in XML String

Tags: vb.net

I am adding onclick attributes to the buttong and  passing String mystring. mystring is the basically xml string. In xml string there is one tag which has value as " non-digit/letter in value 'COMM TEST' ". I am passing xml string as an agr to the javascript function `DisplayFlightMessage` here is the code

```
 msgButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "DisplayFlightMessage('" & Utility.EncodeJsString(mystring) & "');return false")
```

The definition of `DisplayFlightMessage` is

```
<script id="DetailCode" type="text/javascript">

function DisplayFlightMessage(msg) {

    var arguments = new ModalDialogArgsCollection();
    arguments.addCollectionItem(msg);
    var url = "../ModalDialogs/FlightStatusMessage.aspx"
    var dialogWidth = 500;
    var dialogWindowHeight = 300;
    var dialogBodyHeight = dialogWindowHeight - 35;

    var opt = "dialogWidth:" + dialogWidth + "px;dialogHeight:" + dialogWindowHeight + "px;center:yes;status:no;scroll:no";
    arguments.style = "width:" + dialogWidth + "px;height:" + dialogBodyHeight + "px;"
    var modalDialogStatus = window.showModalDialog(url, arguments, opt);

}
```

and `EncodeJsString` defined as below

```
  Public Function EncodeJsString(ByVal s As String) As String
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    ' sb.Append("""")
    For Each c As Char In s
        Select Case c
            Case """"c
                sb.Append("\""")
                Exit Select
            Case "\"c
                sb.Append("\\")
                Exit Select
            Case ControlChars.Back
                sb.Append("\b")
                Exit Select
            Case ControlChars.FormFeed
                sb.Append("\f")
                Exit Select
            Case ControlChars.Lf
                sb.Append("\n")
                Exit Select
            Case ControlChars.Cr
                sb.Append("\r")
                Exit Select
            Case ControlChars.Tab
                sb.Append("\t")
                Exit Select
            Case Else
                Dim i As Integer = AscW(c)
                If i < 32 OrElse i > 127 Then
                    sb.AppendFormat("\u{0:X04}", i)
                Else
                    sb.Append(c)
                End If
                Exit Select
        End Select
    Next
    ' sb.Append("""")

    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

As I am passing Single quote character in agr , it consider as comments and it will not open Model box. so I tired to replays " ' " with Char(32) but it will not work as expected .
Any advice how I can handle single quote in this case  ..
Thanks in Advance ..

Comment: Have you tried replacing a single quote with the HTML entity `&#39;`?

Comment: No. let me try that..

Comment: @AndrewMorton not sure how to do that.. still trying ..

Comment: Add a `Case "'"` with `sb.Append("&#39;")`. Incidentally, in VB.NET you don't need the `Exit Select` analogue to C#'s `break`.

Comment: its work  but in the model window instead of " ' " its shows " &#39; "  . I am looking something which shows " ' " in model dialog also.

Comment: Ah, um.... [Single quote escape in JavaScript function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744315/single-quote-escape-in-javascript-function-parameters)... I was thinking that you must have tried `\'` but maybe not.