# Escaping apostrophe (single quote) character in javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a following situation:

I compose a string in javascript that include apostrophe character. That string is actually html code that is later attached to html using `innerHTML` method. So the code looks something like this:

```
var str = '<a href="javascript:foo("ba'r")">link</a>'; (argument of the foo function is string)
```

And after that, this string is inserted into some html element like this:

```
dataHolder.innerHTML = str;
```

I've tried to escape `'` character with `&apos;`, `&#39;` and `\u0027` but all of that is rendered as `'` after `innerHTML` method is called, so when the method `foo` from the example above is called by clicking on link I always get javascript error saying: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: `"javascript:foo(ba\'r)"`

Comment: Still not sure how you "compose a string in JavaScript" and it would get this error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744315/single-quote-escape-in-javascript-function-parameters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape a single quote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428572/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote)

Comment: Look the problem here is not only how to escape the single quote. Even when that's done, the `href` value is going to be incorrect because `ba'r` doesn't mean anything in JavaScript.

Comment: It would be helpful to know exactly what it is you'd like to pass to the function `foo()` when the `<a>` is clicked.

Comment: @Pointy I only want to pass a string containing single quote to javascript function. But I see, here the argument isn't a string, but actually this str variable is just part of the argument which is composed from some more variables, but at the end I have only a string as a parameter.

Comment: Well you're experience exactly the sort of difficulty that makes separating JavaScript and HTML the recommended way of doing things, using DOM APIs to assign functions as event handlers. It's a real mess to do it via string building code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have both `'` and `"` in your string, so you will need a third way to delcare a string, you can use [template strings](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings) for that. Declare your `ba'r` string as a template string and escape its apostrophe using a backslash `\`:

```js
document.querySelector('#myDiv').innerHTML =
    '<a href="javascript:foo(`ba\'r`)">link</a>';

function foo(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Looking at the first row of your code, if you call the frunction `bar` with string argument containing single quote :`foo("ba\'r")'` it will be escaped before the call of `innerHTML`, but after that `\'` will become `'` and produce the javascript error.

Comment: Oh I see, I updated the answer with an apostrophe like this `ba'r`

Answer (score 1):

use `\'` instead of `'` inside the string, so it should be

`var str = '<a href="javascript:foo(ba\'r)">link</a>';`

However, this code is just correct in string format aspect. I think what you want could be

`var str = '<a href="javascript:foo(\'bar\')">link</a>';`

Comment: And the code *still* won't work, because that's a JavaScript syntax error when the `<a>` is clicked.

Comment: Ahhh, true, I was just thinking about string aspect :D

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the backtick ` to avoid this problem:

```
var str = `<a href="javascript:foo(ba'r)">link</a>`;
```