# Escaping single quotes that is in single quotes which is in double quotes

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code which is broken. due to single and double quotes.

How should i escape it to get it working?

```
<a href="path" rel="example_group" title="<a href='/Home/Vote/@item.Id'><img src='/Content/images/021.png' style='float:left; margin-left:45%;' /></a><a onClick='window.open('test.com','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');' href='javascript: void(0)'><img src='/Content/images/022.png' /></a>"><img  src="@Url.Action("ViewImage", "Image", new { id = item.Id, imageType="thumb" })" alt="" width="100" height="100" /> </a>
```

`window.open` is breaking it.

How can i fix this? I tried escaping but no luck.

**Please see that this code is in Title of a. so I can't use double quotes.**

Comment: at the end of `<a onClick='window.open('test.com','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');' href='javascript: void(0)'><img src='/Content/images/022.png' /></a>">` is that an erranious `"` at `</a>">'` or am I mistaken? Because I see nothing matching with it at all. I believe you want a `<a onClick= "` instead of `<a onClick= '`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes inside the single quotes.

`<a onClick='window.open("test.com","sharer","toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325");'`

Or open and close it with double quotes

`<a onClick="window.open('test.com','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');"`

**EDIT**

You can use `&quot;` in place of the double quote. If you need to write this HTML back out somewhere, you can replace the `&quot;` with `"` at that time.

**EDIT**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015345/how-to-properly-escape-quotes-inside-html-attributes) similar SO question may help.

Comment: please read the question. double quote is being used at title.

Comment: All of this HTML is in the title text?

Comment: @DarthVader I just don't see the need to ever write HTML that looks like this. It's confusing and difficult to maintain (as you are clearly finding out).

Comment: ask me . that s a feature of fancybox and what u said worked actually. &quot; did it. thanks

Comment: Heh. Yeah. No problem. Missed that important piece. And you never know what level of expertise you're working with on SO, I try not to take much for granted. :)