# jQuery parse string data

Tags: jquery, json, html-parsing

My simulation results are acquired from REST service which contains strings and numerical values. I am able to parse the numerical ones (`x_water`), but have difficulties with the strings (`x_date`). Below is my approach, and I guess maybe I am wrong in using HTML5 `data-val` attribute to store strings. So could anyone gives me some suggestions?

My data looks like below

`x_water`

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.1, 0.0545, 0.000171, 3.71e-05, 3.61e-05, 3.54e-05, 3.48e-05, 3.42e-05, 3.35e-05, 3.3e-05, 3.24e-05, 3.18e-05, 3.12e-05, 3.06e-05, 3.01e-05, 2.95e-05, 2.9e-05, 2.85e-05, 2.79e-05, 2.74e-05, 2.69e-05, 2.64e-05, 2.59e-05, 2.54e-05, 2.5e-05, 2.45e-05, 2.41e-05, 2.36e-05, 2.32e-05, 2.28e-05, 2.23e-05, 2.19e-05]
```

`x_date`

```
[' 1/ 1/1961', ' 1/ 2/1961', ' 1/ 3/1961', ' 1/ 4/1961', ' 1/ 5/1961', ' 1/ 6/1961', ' 1/ 7/1961', ' 1/ 8/1961', ' 1/ 9/1961', ' 1/10/1961', ' 1/11/1961', ' 1/12/1961', ' 1/13/1961', ' 1/14/1961', ' 1/15/1961', ' 1/16/1961', ' 1/17/1961', ' 1/18/1961', ' 1/19/1961', ' 1/20/1961', ' 1/21/1961', ' 1/22/1961', ' 1/23/1961', ' 1/24/1961', ' 1/25/1961', ' 1/26/1961', ' 1/27/1961', ' 1/28/1961', ' 1/29/1961', ' 1/30/1961', ' 1/31/1961', ' 2/ 1/1961', ' 2/ 2/1961', ' 2/ 3/1961', ' 2/ 4/1961', ' 2/ 5/1961', ' 2/ 6/1961', ' 2/ 7/1961', ' 2/ 8/1961', ' 2/ 9/1961', ' 2/10/1961', ' 2/11/1961', ' 2/12/1961']
```

In python, I put them in a hidden html table like below:

```
html = html + """
<table class="results" width="550" border="1">
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col" colspan="3"><div align="center">Results</div></th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr style="display: none">
                    <td id="x_water" data-val='%s'></td>
                    <td id="x_date" data-val='%s'></td>
                  </tr>
</table><br>"""%(x_water,x_date)
```

The last step is use jQuery to grab those two variables:

```
    var x_water = $.parseJSON($('#x_water').attr('data-val'));
    var x_date = $.parseJSON($('#x_date').attr('data-val'));
```

I checked the source of the generated html file:

```
<td id="x_water" data-val='[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.1, 0.0545, 0.000171, 3.71e-05, 3.61e-05, 3.54e-05, 3.48e-05, 3.42e-05, 3.35e-05, 3.3e-05, 3.24e-05, 3.18e-05, 3.12e-05, 3.06e-05, 3.01e-05, 2.95e-05, 2.9e-05, 2.85e-05, 2.79e-05, 2.74e-05, 2.69e-05, 2.64e-05, 2.59e-05, 2.54e-05, 2.5e-05, 2.45e-05, 2.41e-05, 2.36e-05, 2.32e-05, 2.28e-05, 2.23e-05, 2.19e-05]'></td>
<td id="x_date" data-val='[' 1/ 1/1961', ' 1/ 2/1961', ' 1/ 3/1961', ' 1/ 4/1961', ' 1/ 5/1961', ' 1/ 6/1961', ' 1/ 7/1961', ' 1/ 8/1961', ' 1/ 9/1961', ' 1/10/1961', ' 1/11/1961', ' 1/12/1961', ' 1/13/1961', ' 1/14/1961', ' 1/15/1961', ' 1/16/1961', ' 1/17/1961', ' 1/18/1961', ' 1/19/1961', ' 1/20/1961', ' 1/21/1961', ' 1/22/1961', ' 1/23/1961', ' 1/24/1961', ' 1/25/1961', ' 1/26/1961', ' 1/27/1961', ' 1/28/1961', ' 1/29/1961', ' 1/30/1961', ' 1/31/1961', ' 2/ 1/1961', ' 2/ 2/1961', ' 2/ 3/1961', ' 2/ 4/1961', ' 2/ 5/1961', ' 2/ 6/1961', ' 2/ 7/1961', ' 2/ 8/1961', ' 2/ 9/1961', ' 2/10/1961', ' 2/11/1961', ' 2/12/1961']'></td>
```

My Chrome JS console did not help a lot, but only complains:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

Comment: You should probably pass valid JSON to a function that parses JSON ?

Comment: You are right. I need to convert x_date using json.dump first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes are not properly escaped.
Check this page out

[How to properly escape quotes inside html attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015345/how-to-properly-escape-quotes-inside-html-attributes)

Also here is a fiddle of the correct use in action

http://jsfiddle.net/earlonrails/LUDh8/3/

```
<td id="x_water" data-val='[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.1, 0.0545, 0.000171, 3.71e-05, 3.61e-05, 3.54e-05, 3.48e-05, 3.42e-05, 3.35e-05, 3.3e-05, 3.24e-05, 3.18e-05, 3.12e-05, 3.06e-05, 3.01e-05, 2.95e-05, 2.9e-05, 2.85e-05, 2.79e-05, 2.74e-05, 2.69e-05, 2.64e-05, 2.59e-05, 2.54e-05, 2.5e-05, 2.45e-05, 2.41e-05, 2.36e-05, 2.32e-05, 2.28e-05, 2.23e-05, 2.19e-05]'></td>
<td id="x_date" data-val="[ &quot;1/ 1/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/ 2/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/ 3/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/ 4/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/ 5/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/ 6/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/ 7/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/ 8/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/ 9/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/10/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/11/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/12/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/13/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/14/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/15/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/16/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/17/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/18/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/19/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/20/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/21/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/22/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/23/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/24/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/25/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/26/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/27/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/28/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/29/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/30/1961&quot;, &quot; 1/31/1961&quot;, &quot; 2/ 1/1961&quot;, &quot; 2/ 2/1961&quot;, &quot; 2/ 3/1961&quot;, &quot; 2/ 4/1961&quot;, &quot; 2/ 5/1961&quot;, &quot; 2/ 6/1961&quot;, &quot; 2/ 7/1961&quot;, &quot; 2/ 8/1961&quot;, &quot; 2/ 9/1961&quot;, &quot; 2/10/1961&quot;, &quot; 2/11/1961&quot;, &quot; 2/12/1961&quot;]"></td>
```

Comment: This is why you got the error, and I believe it to be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the data at page load time, I would suggest simply outputting it directly in javascript as an object literal:

```
html = html + """
<script type="javascript">
var x_water = %s;
var x_date = %s;
</script>"""%(x_water,x_date);
```

Comment: Will this approach slow down the webpage speed?