# Include single quote to string

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to have a dropdown from MySQL data where I want `<option value ='and acode ='Aircraft1''>`, including the two single quotes to pass it into a query. I'm including backslash already but it's not working. What's wrong with my code?

```
<?php    
$asql = "SELECT * FROM aircraft";
$aresult = mysql_query($asql);
?>
Aircraft:
<select name="aircraft">
<option value="and (acode = 'RP-C1086' or acode='RP-C1728')" checked/>All</option> 
<?php while($arow=mysql_fetch_array($aresult))
{
  echo "<option value='and acode=\'".$arow['reg']."\''>".$arow['reg']."</option>";
} ?>
</select>
```

Comment: First you must quit using mysql_* as it is deprecated, then you should learn about prepared statements to prevent injection. Use mysqli or PDO! And instead of `echo "<option value='and acode=\'".$arow['reg']."\''>".$arow['reg']."</option>";` use `echo "<option value=\"and acode='".$arow['reg']."'\">".$arow['reg']."</option>";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html):

> There are several ways to include quote characters within a string:
>
> - A `“'”` inside a string quoted with `“'”` may be written as `“''”`.
> - A `“"”` inside a string quoted with `“"”` may be written as `“""”`.
> - Precede the quote character by an escape character (`“\”`).
> - A `“'”` inside a string quoted with `“"”` needs no special treatment and need not be doubled or escaped. In the same way, `“"”` inside a string quoted with `“'”` needs no special treatment.

When coding in php, remember to use `\\` in a string literal to get a single `\` in the string value.

If you want to escape the quote in an HTML attribute, replace the `'` with `&quot;`. Alternatively, quote the attribute value with `"`. These are the techniques to use regardless of where the string value came from. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015345/how-to-properly-escape-quotes-inside-html-attributes).

Comment: I want to get the single quote `'` in the string, not the slash.

Comment: @xjshiya - Ah. This isn't a MySQL question then. I updated my answer.