# How to remain my inputs after page refreshed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Does anyone know how to make inputs in a `textbox` and `selectbox` remain after page refreshed?

I want to make my inputs remain afer page refreshed if the user unable to fill all the required filleds in a registration page.

Comment: you can use SESSION if you are using PHP, or using cookie (Can be used by PHP or just client side JavaScript).

Comment: Or you can do the validation client-side and not let them refresh until everything is correct

Answer (score 1):

you should validate your form  before sending it to server, in client side with javascript

Answer (score 0):

set the value of the field to the posted value eg:

```
<form method="POST">
<input name="username" value="<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Don't forget to escape said value. In it's current form, one could inject javascript events onto that input (or simply break the input, causing loss of the previous data)

Comment: @KevinB interesting point. could you recommend a php built in for escaping?

Comment: I'm sure there's some simple method for it, i'm not a php coder so i would have to google for it. in ColdFusion it's called `HTMLEditFormat`.

Comment: It's contained within one of the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015345/how-to-properly-escape-quotes-inside-html-attributes

Comment: seems `filter_input()` would do the trick, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant **'form submit'** by **'page refresh'**. Here how you do it.

**For text fields:**

```
<input type="text" name="text_field" value="<?php echo @$_POST['text_field']"; ?>/>
```

**For select fields:**

```
<select name="select_field">
    <option value="1" <?php echo @$_POST['select_field'] == "1" ? "selected" : '' ?>>an Option</option>
    <option value="2" <?php echo @$_POST['select_field'] == "2" ? "selected" : '' ?>>another Option</option>
</select>
```

**NOTE:** `@` symbols is to suppress the error when you load the page for the first time.

Hope this helps :)