# ng-repeat: populate drop down options with array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple JavaScript object that looks like this:

```
$scope.obj = { "'Architect'": ["asdf","d","e","y"]};
```

I'd like to show the values of `'Architect'` in a select box. However, the single quotes are throwing me off when trying to do the `ng-repeat`.

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="row in obj['Architect']" value="{{row}}">{{row}}</option>
</select>
```

That does not populate the select box, it just shows an empty select box. I assume it is interpreting the single quotes as a string literal, but even if I add single quotes and escape them, it still doesn't work as expected. Am I missing something?

[Here is a sample plunker:](http://plnkr.co/edit/BKlRPPxp5L0QjPZcozGh?p=preview)

Comment: This might be a silly question as you might have a good reason for the quotes... but have you tried removing them? http://plnkr.co/edit/tOxov9wOVspXiQiF4P1W?p=preview

Comment: I'd like to remove them, but I work for a large company, and the data I get has quotes. I can't alter the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

escape the quotes [How to properly escape quotes inside html attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015345/how-to-properly-escape-quotes-inside-html-attributes)

```
<option ng-repeat="row in obj[&quot;'Architect'&quot;]" value="{{row}}">{{row}}</option>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/6xUD3Zg0jxV05b41f2Gw?p=preview

Comment: You could also use `<option ng-repeat="row in obj['\'Architect\'']" value="{{row}}">{{row}}</option>`

Comment: &quot; is the html entity for quotes.

Comment: I'm actually surprised this works given that those should be decoded and then interpreted as two unescaped quotes by JS. Interesting.

Comment: yes but why is needed? Architect is in quotes it self. why is the second one need?

Comment: The single quotes are interpreted as a string literal, not as part of the string.

Comment: awu i found. in the this is obj["'Architect'"]  but I think this is odd too :D why don't you use obj["Architect"]?

Comment: If I used double quotes, it would terminate the `ng-repeat` attribute.

Comment: no, i mean in definition $scope.obj = { "'Architect'": ["asdf","d","e","y"]}; why didn't you use $scope.obj = { "Architect" : ... }. why did you use the "'Architect'" instead of "Architect"?

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use "ng-options" for select?
take a lock at this 
[AngularJs API: select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code for ng repeat with external json

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>datatable using jquery.datatable in angularjs</title> 
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> 
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" ng-app="problemApp" data-ng-controller="validationCtrl">
  <select>
    <option ng-repeat="item in testdata" value="">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
</div>
  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js'></script>
<script  src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
var app=angular.module('problemApp', []);
app.controller('validationCtrl',function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('http://localhost/Dtable_angular/ngrepeatdropdown/test.json').success(function (data) {

                $scope.testdata = data;
                console.log($scope.testdata)
        })


$scope.dataTableOpt = {
   //custom datatable options 
  // or load data through ajax call also
  "aLengthMenu": [[10, 50, 100,-1], [10, 50, 100,'All']],
  };
});
```

### test.json

```
[{
        "countryId": 1,
        "name": "France - Mainland",
        "desc": "some description"
    },
    {
        "countryId": 2,
        "name": "Gibraltar",
        "desc": "some description"
    },
    {
        "countryId": 3,
        "name": "Malta",
        "desc": "some description"
    }
]
```