# Create input type="button" with two lines of text for newer version of chrome

Tags: html, css

**I will accept an answer of "not possible" if someone can explain why. However, I will not except an answer with using a `<button>` because that is not what this question is asking.**

I am trying to make an input button with two lines of words, but the newer versions of chrome are not letting me, here is what I have tried:

Carriage Return Separators

```html
    <input type="button" value="Line One&#13;&#10;Line Two"/>

    <input type="button" value="Line One\r\nLine Two">
```

I know you can use `white-space: normal;` but this will not let you `<br>` where you want it to.

```
input[type="submit"] {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Is there a way that I can add the new line in the button where I choose?

i.e.

> line one
>
> line two

Comment: You can use `<button>` instead of `<input>` — `<button type="submit">Line One<br>Line Two</button>` https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.submit.html

Comment: @StephenP I know about buttons, trying to do it with `<input type="button"/>` any idea's?

Comment: Is there any reason you prefer <input type='submit' />?

Comment: I will accept an answer of "not possible" if someone can explain why. However, I will not except an answer with using a `<button>` because that is not what this question is asking.

Comment: @swa66 read the first line of the question.

Comment: @swa66 good thing I do not have to report my reasoning to you, have a good weekend!

Comment: It was a serious question... but oh well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Although I can't prove that it's *not possible*, it's not a good idea to try to make the `input` button take up multiple lines. First of all, the [HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#submit-button-state-(type=submit)) says only this about the `value` attribute:

> If the element has a value attribute, the button's label must be the value of that attribute

Notice that "button's label" is not defined anywhere in the spec. That means it is up to browser vendors to choose how to interpret that, and it also means that they can change their interpretation at will.

You just witnessed the Chrome team deciding to make such a change. It could happen again, in another browser perhaps. So any solution you find now will not be permanent and subject to the whims of browser vendors.

That's why I strongly recommend using the `<button>` element. Because it is guaranteed by the spec to allow you to do HTML formatting, like line breaks.

Comment: This would be the most "on topic" answer thus far. Thanks.

Comment: What I am interested in learning is what actually changed, it used to be possible now it is not. Firefox still works and older version of chrome also work.

Answer (score 8):

@aardrian has pointed the right direction, you also have to set `-webkit-appearance` as `none` to remove specific styling of the input.

**CSS**

```
input {
  white-space: normal;
  width: 50px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;

  background: #ddd;
  border: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" value="Text1 Text2 Text3 Text4" />
```

[image]

You can change the width to allow more words in each row.

**Codepen**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xOExpX

It's seems there's no way to add html inside the value, the *value* value is always sanitized:

> The value content attribute gives the default value of the input
>   element. When the value content attribute is added, set, or removed,
>   if the control's dirty value flag is false, the user agent must set
>   the value of the element to the value of the value content attribute,
>   if there is one, or the empty string otherwise, and then run the
>   current value sanitization algorithm, if one is defined.

**Info**: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-value

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to answer, however, I am looking for a solution that you can "break" a line anywhere you like ie  `Text1 \n Text2 Text3 \n Text4` Since I am starting to realize this seems to not be possible, I will except an answer describing why it is not possible. I will up-vote your answer since you took time to try to answer and I apologize if I was not clear enough.

Comment: Like this example https://jsfiddle.net/ynz25v2x/ but with `<input>` not a `<button>`

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've understood what you need but as far as I'm know it's not possible, value field doesn't accept html.

Comment: It doesn't need to be in the value attribute, is there a different attribute I can use?

Comment: I just came across this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015345/how-to-properly-escape-quotes-inside-html-attributes also no longer works, I guess newer version of chrome doesn't allow for any of this.

Comment: The only thing i could came out is putting a label over the input, just an idea http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bewNVE

Comment: If you accept a variation of setting a width to force wrapping (which I know does not allow arbitrary breaks), make sure the width is in a unit relative to the base text size — such as `em`. This way as the user changes text size, or the font itself fails to display (network issues), it will still scale based on the size of the letters that do display.

Answer (score 4):

Hack:

```
input[type="submit"] {
    white-space: normal;
    width: 7em;
}
```

The width should correspond to the longest word. This does not allow arbitrary line breaks.

Better solution: use `<button>`.

Comment: Note that I use a unit relative to the base text size — `em`. This way as the user changes text size, or the font itself fails to display (network issues), it will still scale based on the size of the letters that do display. IOW, do not use `px` as it does not scale with the text.

Answer (score 3):

Use `<button type=submit>` instead.

```html
<button type=submit>First line<br>Second line</button>
```

Comment: I know about buttons, trying to do it with `<input type="button"/>` any idea's? or is it not possible?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith: Why do you insist on using an `<input>`? Button is clearly the best, non-hacky choice here. We could probably help you more if we knew *why* you need an `<input>`.

Comment: I have a bounty on this question now, if you give me an answer with not possible but why its not possible, I will except that.

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding it is not possible to achieve what you wish with input.  The attribute "value" will treat everything inside as a string that is to be printed out to the screen.  So any `<br />` tags will just get treated as text and will not be rendered as HTML.  It does not accepts any escape characters.

Your best option is to use button as c-smile suggests or you can create a div, style it to your liking and add a javascript on click which will cause a form submission.

Alternatively, if you strongly believe you have to use input you can do a bit of javascript (this is only if you don't know what the words are the width is unknown).

For the record, I strongly advise just use a button, here is how you do it:

https://jsfiddle.net/bdLanac5/1/

```js
 var inputValue = $("#myInput").val();
    var inputValues = inputValue.split(" ");
    var longestValue = inputValues.reduce(function (a, b) { return a.length > b.length ? a : b; });
    
    $("#myInput").val(longestValue);
    var length = $("#myInput").outerWidth();
    $("#myInput").css("width", length);
    $("#myInput").val(inputValue);
```

```css
    input{
      white-space: normal;
    }
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="submit" value="This is a test"/>
```

If you know the width then remove the javascript and add width on css to your input element.

Comment: Thanks, closets possible answer to the question +1

Answer (score 2):

Could this be useful? Not exactly what you asked, I know...

(<strike>notice the font difference too</strike> since I got a few upvotes I took care of the font issue)

```css
input{
  font-family:inherit;
  font-size:inherit;
}
#line1{
  padding-bottom: 25px; 
  padding-left:5px;
  text-align:left;
  width:75px;/*Depends on the second line lengh*/
}
#line2{ 
  margin-top: -23px; 
  padding-left:7px;  
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Line One" id="line1"/>
<div id="line2">Line Two</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat of a hack, but you could use regular spaces where you want the line to break, and nbsp where you don't - then just make sure the width is set to house it correctly.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asimovwasright/ynz25v2x/4/)

```css
    input{
     white-space: normal;
     width: 110px;
    }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Text1&#160;Text2&#160;Text3 Text4" />
```

Comment: Thanks, however this does not work for the newer versions of chrome.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me? Maybe I as a linux user I get a slightly different build of chrome?

Comment: Are you using chrome ver 51.xxx?

Comment: Version 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit)

Comment: but m still unsatisfied with your answer coz @AdamBuchananSmith said that , don't use white-space property

Comment: Indeed, and I am not hoping to be awarded the points, only offering an alternative that might negate the reasons for not wanting the white-space hack in the first place.

Comment: @AnkitGupta The whitespace would be ok since the answer is using `&#160;` to break the line, however it just doesn't work on chrome and IE11

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="myInput" type="submit" value="Line OneLine Two"/>

input{
  white-space: normal;
  word-break: break-all;
}

#myInput{
  width:73px;
}
```

You can give your own width to button.