# Multiple doublequotes in input value

Tags: php

I want to ask if it is possible to add multiple double quotes to the input value, like this:

```
<input value= "<iframe src="http://xxx.xx/embed?t=<?php the_title(); ?>" 
width='640' height='360'
allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true'
scrolling='no' frameborder='0'></iframe>"
```

So, the whole `<iframe>` element is wrapped within double quotes, just as the value of the `src` attribute (the URL), but the URL will not be included in value.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping quotation marks in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php)

Comment: Its not duplicate, i have html value not php, it doesnt work for html

Comment: Why did you tag your question with [php] then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try escaping double quotation with backslash..... 
For more info visit [How to properly escape quotes inside html attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015345/how-to-properly-escape-quotes-inside-html-attributes)

```
<input value= "<iframe src=&quot;http://xxx.xx/embed?t=<?php the_title(); ?>&quot; 
width=&quot;640&quot; height=&quot;360&quot;
allowscriptaccess=&quot;always&quot; allowfullscreen=&quot;true&quot;
scrolling=&quot;no&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot;></iframe>"
```