# Escaping in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, escaping, freemarker, html-escape-characters

How do I make this work?

`<a href='javascript:func("Jack'S Birthday")'>Jack's Birthday</a>`

Comment: Any reason you need to abuse `href` for JavaScript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do as follows:

```js
// How about using variables instead?
var emily = "Emily'S Birthday"
var birthdays = {
  john: "John'S Birthday"
}

function func(val) {
  console.log(val);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <a href='javascript:func("Jack&apos;S Birthday")'>Jack's Birthday</a>
  <br>
  <a href="javascript:func('Norman\'S Birthday')">Norman's Birthday</a>
  <br>
  <a href="javascript:func(emily)">Emily's Birthday</a>
  <br>
  <a href="javascript:func(birthdays.john)">John's Birthday</a>
</body>

</html>
```

> Explanation:

1. Keep single quotes within double quotes when you escape using backslash `\`
2. Use double quotes within single quotes when you use `$apos;`
3. Best of all, use variables, they ease a lot of pain -

   a. You don't have to go into html to modify values,
   b. these can be declared at one place, or a single file,
   c. They can be fetched from back-end
   d. Best yet, no need to deal with quotes!

Comment: Thanks. But none of the above actually shows Norman'S Birthday. It does say Norman\'S Birthday with a "\".

Comment: @jforex78 But I see the result without the back slash!

Comment: i see - i'll try this and mark the answer thereafter. thank you.

Comment: Thanks - this works in JavaScript. I've edited my question to show the production problem we are having with FTL expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can't escape characters within HTML attributes. The proper way to go would be to use HTML entities like `&apos;` :

```html
<a href='javascript:console.log("&apos;")'>click me</a>
```

See [How to properly escape quotes inside html attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4015345/1636522).

Answer (score 0):

If possible, do it this way

```
<html>
  <header>
    <script>
    function func(x) {
      alert(x);
    }</script>
  </header>
  <body>
    <a href="javascript:func('Norman\'S Birthday')">Birthday</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If possible, an actual button should be used, and `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to NCR. This should work.

```
<html>
    <a href='javascript:func("Norman&#39;S Birthday")'>Birthday</a>
</html>
```

Or.

```
<html>
    <a href='javascript:func("Norman&#x27;S Birthday")'>Birthday</a>
</html>
```