# Using Single Quotes in HTML data- attribute with an array

Tags: html, attributes, double-quotes, single-quotes

Suppose I have this line of HTML

```
<div data-stuff='["Hi", "I'm a", "String"]'></div>
```

Obviously this will be a problem. How can I escape the single quote under > I'm? 
Am I forced to use ASCII code `&#39;`? or is there an alternative?

Comment: '["Hi", "I\'\m a", "String"]' should work.

Comment: I thought so too. but it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly escape quotes inside html attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015345/how-to-properly-escape-quotes-inside-html-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `'["Hi", "I&rsquo;m a", "String"]'`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.