# html Popover quotations and inverted comma's in the wrong place?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im having an issue with the structure of a popover. When the popover is structured like the below, it flows as designed but Im missing an ID in the onclick function.

```
<td align="center"><input type="image" data-placement="left" data-toggle="popover" style="height:25px; width:25px" src="<?php echo ABSPATH; ?>/uploads/settings_icon.png" data-content='<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="test();">Delete</a>' ></td>
```

When I add the missing ID into the onclick function as mentioned, it breaks the button. Please see the below code...

```
<td align="center"><input type="image" data-placement="left" data-toggle="popover" style="height:25px; width:25px" src="<?php echo ABSPATH; ?>/uploads/settings_icon.png" data-content='<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="test(**'<?php echo $id;?>'**);">Delete</a>' ></td>
```

This is the outcome of the above line...
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJWfL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape your quotes inside the `test()` function call. You're already inside some single quotes that are used for the `data-content` attribute you're defining. When you use your first single quote inside the `test()` call, you're effectively ending the `data-content` attribute.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015345/how-to-properly-escape-quotes-inside-html-attributes) might help you further.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is necessary to echo $id within quotes. Try:

```
<td align="center"><input type="image" data-placement="left" data-toggle="popover" style="height:25px; width:25px" src="<?php echo ABSPATH; ?>/uploads/settings_icon.png" data-content='<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="test(**<?php echo $id;?>**);">Delete</a>' ></td>
```

Comment: I have tried this and the error : Uncaught ReferenceError: c68c044a69b14fa3b689abd16b0e2486 is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick ((index):1)

Comment: @MichaelvE would be correct if the ID was purely numeric, as that doesn't have to be a string in Javascript. But you have a hex value as your ID, which needs quoting as it's a string.