# Quotation marks in textarea placeholder

Tags: html, textarea, placeholder

This should be pretty straight forward.... I would like the `placeholder` text in a `textarea` to display quotation marks. As in "HELLO".

I tried the usually-reliable "\"Hello\"" but that doesn't work.... it outputs simply \ because it sees that contained between opening and closing quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly escape quotes inside html attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015345/how-to-properly-escape-quotes-inside-html-attributes)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `&quot;` for the quotation mark symbol. For example:

```
<textarea name="content" placeholder="&quot;Hello&quot;"></textarea>
```

Comment: I guess that that is the easiest.... but out of curiosity, is there no backslash method to force characters?

Comment: @PaulClift — ```\``` has no special meaning in HTML.