# Adding custom link to href tag

Tags: php, html

I am trying to add a custom link to the href tag using the following code

```
<input type="text" id="bootstrap_css_link_script" aria-hidden="true" 
 class="offscreen form-control" value="<?php echo "<link 
 href='".$bootstrap_css_link."'>"; ?>">
```

everything is fine but I want to get the href tag in doublequote("") as shown below

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

But after executing the above code I am getting the following result

```
<link href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
```

Comment: Have you tried this ```<?php echo `<link href=".$bootstrap_css_link.">`; ?>```

Answer (score 2):

,Change to single quotes on the outside: Also, if the html attribute is double has a quote inside it needs to be escaped using: `&quot;`

```
<?php echo '<link href=&quot;'.$bootstrap_css_link.'&quot;>'; ?>
```

Also, you can remove echo to save a few clicks and clean up the code inside your HTML:

```
<?='<link href=&quot;'.$bootstrap_css_link.'&quot;>'?>
```

See this stack overflow question for reference: [How to properly escape quotes inside html attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015345/how-to-properly-escape-quotes-inside-html-attributes)

Answer (score 2):

you have to use `\"` for escape a double quotes.
So, your code should be like this

```php
<input type="text" id="bootstrap_css_link_script" aria-hidden="true" 
 class="offscreen form-control" value="<?php echo "<link 
 href=\"".$bootstrap_css_link."\">"; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with single quotes of php

```
      <?php
        $bootstrap_css_link="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css";
      ?>
      <input type="text" id="bootstrap_css_link_script" aria-hidden="true class="offscreen form-control" value="<?php echo '<link href="'.$bootstrap_css_link.'">'; ?>">
```