# How can I pass a PHP array as an argument to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

It's just an example, but with this code, it works. But if I change 5 to **"5"** and 10 to **"10"** I got an *Unexpectid ending syntax error* for the echo line

**PHP**

```
$array = array();
$array[0] = 10;  
$array[1] = 5; 
$json = json_encode($array);

echo "<td style=\"background: red;\"><button onclick=\"modifyModalContent('$day_date_column','$i',$json) ... (really long line)
```

**JS**

```
function modifyModalContent(date, id, array) {
  var header = document.querySelector(".modal-header");
  var body = document.querySelector(".modal-body");

  var table =
  `
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr>    
      <td>${array[0]}<td>
      <td>${array[1]}<td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  `;

  body.innerHTML = table;

  header.innerHTML = `<h1> Date: ${date}</h1></br><h1>ID: ${autoid}</h1>`;
}
```

The two echo line after run:

**That works:**

```
<tr style="height: 137px;"><td style="background: red;"><button onclick="modifyModalContent('2019-01-21','1',[10,5])" ... (long line)
```

**And if I use it with a string array got error on this:**

```
<tr style="height: 137px;"><td style="background: red;"><button onclick="modifyModalContent(2019-01-21,1,["10","5"])" ... (long line)
```

How could I do the same with an array like this:

```
$array = array();
$array[0] = "10";  
$array[1] = "5";
```

I guess the problem is because of the " char, but How could I fix it?

Comment: Look at the output of the problem line, you have unescaped quotes in quotes, you need to escape them

Comment: I see it, but what can I do with it? Can I replace it?

Comment: You can do `$json = str_replace('"', "'", json_encode($array));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly escape quotes inside html attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015345/how-to-properly-escape-quotes-inside-html-attributes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using the PHP function `htmlspecialchars` -- that will not only take care of issues with quotes, but any other characters (&, <, >} that should be turned into HTML entities before being used as HTML attribute values.

`$json = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($array));`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `["10","5"]` with `['10','5']`

More information about simple and double quotes: [When to use double or single quotes in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-to-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript)

Comment: The array is in a variable, I call it like modifyModalContent('$day_date_column','$i',$json). Can I change the " to ' in that $json array ?

Comment: Yes you can do it with PHP