# input value with " sing

Tags: html, sql

i have this input

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="כפר חב"ד" name="city" >
```

my problem is when the value is insert in to the db i get this
כפר חב
the last letter and the " sing is gone
how can I make it work?

Comment: Replace the `"` with `&quot;`. Possible duplicate of [How to properly escape quotes inside html attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015345/how-to-properly-escape-quotes-inside-html-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

Change the double quotes on the outside to single quotes:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value='כפר חב"ד' name="city" >
```

Comment: i cant . my form is in echo ' (content of form)   '

Comment: @user10498931 You mean PHP's `echo`? Then you can (And should) use [htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: yes.  next time please tag your question with php if you are using php to generate your html.