# Jsoup select for quoted text

Tags: html, css-selectors, jsoup

I have html tag like this:

`<img src="/someLink" class="class" alt="some info "quoted info", some info" />`

I need to select this tag by 'alt' value by the means of jsoup.

I've tried these options:

`img[alt="some info "quoted info", some info"]`

`img[alt="some info \"quoted info\", some info"]`

Nothing worked.

Please explain - how to properly select some element by parameter that includes quotation marks ?

Thank you.

Comment: are you sure this is a valid html?  _<img src="/someLink" class="class" alt="some info "quoted info", some info" />_

Comment: I am noob in the html world, but this is example from real website that I am trying to get info from. Without real class names, links and etc. of course.

Comment: inside alt="some info quoted info" you have an extra quote. this is not correct.[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015345/how-do-i-properly-escape-quotes-inside-html-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015345/how-do-i-properly-escape-quotes-inside-html-attributes)