# How to send string with quotation marks to controller with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

The `input`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="TestProp" value="\"Test\", NS">
```

Ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: window.testUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $("#Form").serialize(),
        success:..
```

The serialized Form returns
`TestProp=`, so this is where the data gets lost.
Any ideas on how to serialize form data with quotation marks string?

Comment: what does it equal? nothing?

Comment: `"\"Test\", NS"` - That's not how you escape double quotes in an HTML attribute -> [How do I properly escape quotes inside HTML attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015345/how-do-i-properly-escape-quotes-inside-html-attributes) -> `&quot;`

Comment: &quot; is the solution. Thank you.